# CentOS 7 SSH and 2FA (ESET Secure Authentication)

Tags: centos, ssh, authentication, pam, radius

I am stuck at getting two factor-authentication in CentOS 7 to work; specifically the authentication via SSH and OTP.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could assist me with this. :)

**Edit:** As I understand it from the log below, the pam module asks the RADIUS-Server for authentication, the server responds with code 11 so that the pam-module challenges the user for an OTP but instead the module just says "authentication failed". So the client should be the problem, right?

Here is a log of an attempt to login via SSH with the account "ws-admin@test.local":

```
sshd[3652]: pam_radius_auth: Got user name ws-admin@test.local
sshd[3652]: pam_radius_auth: ignore last_pass, force_prompt set
sshd[3652]: pam_radius_auth: Sending RADIUS request code 1
sshd[3652]: pam_radius_auth: DEBUG: getservbyname(radius, udp) returned 0x7fa56490e1c0.
sshd[3652]: pam_radius_auth: Got RADIUS response code 11
sshd[3652]: pam_radius_auth: authentication failed
sshd[3652]: pam_sepermit(sshd:auth): Parsing config file:     /etc/security/sepermit.conf
sshd[3652]: pam_sepermit(sshd:auth): Enforcing mode, access will be allowed on match
sshd[3652]: pam_sepermit(sshd:auth): sepermit_match returned: -1
sshd[3652]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.0.0.31 user=ws-admin@test.local
sshd[3652]: Failed password for ws-admin@test.local from 10.0.0.31 port 57962 ssh2
sshd[3652]: Connection closed by 10.0.0.31 [preauth]
```

---

**Below follow Configuration- and Setup-Infos**

The test-environment is given by my companys infrastructure; we mainly use Windows-Clients and about the same share of Windows- and Linux-Servers.

**Win-Server:** Windows Server 2016 x64

- Active Directory: Test.local
- ESET Secure Authentication (RADIUS Server)

  - Shared Secret with Client: test345
  - Option "Use Access-Challenge feature of RADIUS" is enabled

**Linux-Client/Server:** CentOS 7.3 x64

- joined Domain Test.local via realm
- Local Login with AD-Accounts and OTP-2FA at all times possible
- SSH Login with any Account only possible if pam_radius_auth.so not set to required in /etc/pam.d/sshd (which means no 2FA)

---

**Configuration** of the Linux-Client/Server:

- RADIUS-Server and Shared-Secret are added in /etc/raddb/server
- pam_radius_auth.so is in /usr/lib64/security/
- auth required pam_radius_auth.so added to /etc/pam.d/sshd and /etc/pam.d/login

---

**/etc/pam.d/login**

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth [user_unknown=ignore success=ok ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_securetty.so
auth       substack     system-auth
auth       include      postlogin
auth       sufficient   pam_radius_auth.so
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_console.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      system-auth
session    include      postlogin
-session   optional     pam_ck_connector.so
```

**/etc/pam.d/sshd**

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_radius_auth.so    debug
auth       required pam_sepermit.so      debug
auth       substack     password-auth      debug
auth       include      postlogin     debug
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```

**/etc/raddb/server**

```
# server[:port] shared_secret      timeout (s)
10.0.0.1        test345            5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem by myself.

Apparently the only thing to change was the order of pam-modules in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.

The line `auth     sufficient     pam_radius_auth.so` has to be below `pam_sepermit.so` and above `password-auth`.

Actually the order of modules in `/etc/pam.d/login` was not correct either.

There the line `auth     sufficient     pam_radius_auth.so` should be below `pam_securetty.so` and above `system-auth`.

So this is how the files look now:

**/etc/pam.d/login**

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth [user_unknown=ignore success=ok ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_securetty.so
auth       sufficient   pam_radius_auth.so
auth       substack     system-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# auth       sufficient   pam_radius_auth.so
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_console.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      system-auth
session    include      postlogin
-session   optional     pam_ck_connector.so
```

**/etc/pam.d/sshd**

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required pam_sepermit.so
auth       sufficient   pam_radius_auth.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```